# How can I configure TeamCity server to be accessed from other computers on my local network / domain?

Tags: teamcity, firewall-access

I have installed TeamCity on a server machine, but I would like to administer it from other machines. How should I proceed ?

All the machines are on local network and a domain.

Comment: You might as well try to ask on `http://serverfault.com/`, this is a site just as SO, expressly oriented toward technical stuffs, servers, infrastructure, etc. I'm sure they might be of good help too. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allow the TeamCity port in the firewall. This was rather simple.

Comment: How to do it under Windows Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your domain admins, you might find the default rule "World Wide Web Services (HTTP Traffic-In)" allows port 80 traffic, but in my case Programs and Services/Programs was greyed out and fixed to "System" only.

In my case I just needed to add a "TeamCity" rule to allow TCP traffic in for ports, 80, 8080, 9080 and 9090 (change to suit the ports you have set up).